# Dotnetnuke 8 module development error in visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, dotnetnuke

I have successfully installed DNN 8 and all configuration.
i am also referring video to develop module in visual studio.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AKCYRPuoXF4

when i am trying to build the project then
error comes like:

> Error 17  The type or namespace name 'DotNetNuke' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   C:\websites\dnndev.me\DesktopModules\MyDNNModule\MyDNNModuleModuleSettingsBase.cs   13  7   MyDNNModule

Please help to solve that.
thank you in advance.

Comment: What does your line C:\websites\dnndev.me\DesktopModules\MyDNNModule\MyDNNModuleModuleSettingsBase.cs 13 (and/or 7) look like?

Comment: Is your type or namespace established previous to this line?

Comment: Does your Project have a reference to dotnetnuke.dll in the BIN folder?

Comment: no i have not any.@ChrisHammond

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to add a Reference to dotnetnuke.dll in the c:\websites\dnndev.me\bin folder

I honestly haven't done anything with DNN 8 CTP yet, I would stick with 7.4.1 until 8 is official released.

Answer (score 3):

Working with DNN8, sometimes I get a set of errors with message

> The type or namespace name 'DotNetNuke' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

, probably 10 or 15 of them, and all located on top of one ascx file. (My dotnetnuke.dll is correctly placed in DNN's bin folder). Taking a better look (scroll down!), I can see that - except them - there are some more error messages (maybe just one of them), and that those additional errors are perfectly clear and logical. So I correct my source code in order to avoid those additional messages, and when I do that - those problematic messages also disappear!

Comment: yep. but those false errors are annoying cos it's hard to see the real ones. any solutions?

Comment: Yes, me too. Right out of the box (with just an empty project) I was getting exactly 14 of them. See my solution below.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it took me a while to find the solution to this problem, since it only got triggered when I made a change to the `View.ascx` file.

You need the Visual Studio project to *target framework to **4.5** instead of **4.5.1**.*

I got this solution from [here](http://christoc1.rssing.com/chan-11268055/latest.php).