# DotNetNuke - Upgraded 7 to 8 - Can't compile modules now - VS 2010

Tags: module, dotnetnuke

I just upgraded my DotNetNuke site from 7.4.2.216 to 8.0.1.236.  The install seemed to go fine but now when I try to compile any of my modules VS 2010 throws an error saying "The type or namespace name 'DotNetNuke' could not be found".  I removed the reference from the project and re-added it (from the '\BIN' folder), tried to Rebuild but get same error.

Immediately prior to the upgrade my modules compiled fine, there have been no changes made to them other than me trying to re-reference the DotNetNuke.dll file.

I found another thread having a similar issue but in VS 2013 and with no resolution.

[Dotnetnuke 8 module development error in visual studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31747596/dotnetnuke-8-module-development-error-in-visual-studio-2013)

I've searched and searched and haven't found anyone else experiencing this and no info on something similar that might help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to upgrade your projects to .NET 4.5.1, at minimum, they likely are set at .net 4.0

Comment: I moved the project to VS 2015 and targeted .NET 4.5.1 and it worked like a charm!  So glad it was something simple.  TY so much!